# WPF listbox with different colors

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

i have a problem with an listbox that should countain different colors in his Items.

```
    <ListBox i:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems_listbox1}" 
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

Now i want to add an item to the list box were the string is written in different colors for example:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("hallo my name");
```

I want that "hallo"(blue) "my"(red) "name"(green) will be added to the listbox and displayed. 
Is there some possible way to realize this ???

Comment: there are a couple of way to achieve the same. before that you may need to define the rules for colorization. So if you could define them we may attempt to show you the way.

Comment: Do you just want first word blue, second word red, third word green, or the specific words you described?

Comment: Note that using `ItemsSource` will disable using `Items.Add` as well as other modifying usages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight some word, normally we can thought of `RichTextBox` control. However it's not a light weight control. It's fortunate that WPF supports many controls (especially related to `Document`) allowing us to display rich text. For a lightweight solution, you should just use a `TextBlock` representing the content for each `ListViewItem` but we can use the `Run` elements inside each `TextBlock` to highlight the words. Firstly we need to use `DataTemplate` to set `ItemTemplate` for each `ListViewItem`. We have to use `Binding` to bind the string content (of each item) to a `TextBlock` inside the `DataTemplate`. Using `Binding` allows us to inject some custom code in the `Converter`. Here is the details code:

**Code behind**:

```
//The main window class
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Init the Keywords first
        Keywords.Add("hallo", Brushes.Blue);
        Keywords.Add("my", Brushes.Red);
        Keywords.Add("name", Brushes.Green);

        //Add some items to the ListView
        lv.Items.Add("hallo my name");
        lv.Items.Add("hello my name");
        lv.Items.Add("goodbye your name");            
    }
    //This dictionary used to hold your keywords corresponding to their Brush
    public static Dictionary<string, Brush> Keywords = new Dictionary<string,Brush>();
}

//The converter class
public class InlinesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var content = Convert.ToString(value);
        var dict = MainWindow.Keywords;
        var outString = "<TextBlock xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"  xml:space=\"preserve\">";
        foreach(var word in content.Split(' ')){
            var converted = word;
            Brush fg;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(word, out fg)) {
                var run = new Run(word);
                run.Foreground = fg;
                converted = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(run);
            }
            outString += converted + " ";
        }
        outString += "</TextBlock>";            
        return System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(outString);            
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SO3" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    >
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:InlinesConverter x:Key="inlinesConverter"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <ListView Name="lv">            
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                    
                <ContentControl FontSize="20">
                   <Binding Converter="{StaticResource inlinesConverter}"/>
                </ContentControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note about the namespace here, in this demo I used the default namespace `WpfApplication`. If yours is different, you should edit it inside the XAML code. Also note that the `ItemTemplate` is ignored if you add the items right in the XAML code. We have to use the code behind either via `Items.Add` or data binding (with `ItemsSource`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That’s exactly what I have searched.

Answer (score 1):

The Probable way to acheive this might be using the `ListBox DataTemplate` where you will send the string as an array and then inside the `DataTemplate` you can have different TextBlock for all the parts of string

```
<TextBlock Text="hallo " Foreground="Blue" />
<TextBlock Text="my" Foreground="Red" />
<TextBlock Text=" name" Foreground="Green" />
```